# xfreerdp ignores resolution parameter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, resolution

I cannot connect to a server with a custom screen resolution set
If I use command
xfreerdp servername -g 1280x1024
it connects but the resolution is 1024x768. Xfreerdp just carelessly ignores the -g parameter. Any ideas how to fix it or some suggestions for alternative RDP client?
It is
freerdp-x11                               1.0.1-1ubuntu7                            amd64        RDP client for Windows Terminal Services

and I use Ubuntu 12.10 64bit. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had got the same problem for a long time with xfreerdp in Debian 7.
It's a bug because I finally found the reason which concerns the positional parameters on the command line!

-g option is always ignored when after -d option!

Here's my test :

-g option fails when after -d option

-g option succeeds when after -x -a or -u option

Hope this will help...

---

EDIT : 
-t option and -p option fail after -d option

So the rule is : option -d must be the last on the command line!

Comment: This was also helpful to me, thanks. Just to make it clear -- even if not using the `-d` parameter *explicitly*, one should add the server in the end, e.g., `xfreerdp -u username -g 1280x1024 127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 3):

In the recent version that I have (`version 2.0.0-rc4`), one should use `/size:WxH` option:

```
    /size:...   Screen size
```

The `-g` and `-geometry` options are used for other purposes:

```
    /g:<gateway>[:<port>]       Gateway Hostname

    /geometry                   Geometry tracking channel
```

Answer (score 1):

In even more recent versions (2.10.0) it can also scale for HiDPI screens with `/smart-sizing` option. E.g.

`/smart-sizing:1920x1080`

Answer (score 1):

Use `/f` if you want full-screen mode. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to toggle to window mode.